# Set version of Intermediate Value Theorem

Tags: calculus, functions

In *An Introduction to Abstract Mathematics*  (Bond, Keane) they give this

$$\forall \, x \in \mathbb{R},\; \exists \, y \in \mathbb{R} \: \ni \: y^3 = x$$

(They say $\ni$ is "such that.") with the descriptive, *Every real number has a cube root.* Then they say this is a consequence of the Intermediate Value Theorem of Calculus. Can I get some detail on why this is?

**Update**

I guess I'm initially after the basic question of what is it about the set notation of the open sentence makes this a question of continuous-ness? That's what I need to understand first. I see "for all $x$ there exists a $y$ such that $y^3 = x$ and wonder why we're suddenly talking about continuous-ness and the IVT. How did we know to do that? It's like a primitive seeing water and making the leap that it's made of the stuff we breath and the stuff burning in the sun. Huh? all us other primitives say. And *Every real number has a cube root* doesn't help. Again, how is that IVT?

Comment: The Intermediate Value Theorem applied against the function $f$ includes the premise that $f$ is a continuous function throughout the pertinent interval.  $f(x) = x^{(1/3)}$ is known to be a continuous function for all finite real numbers $(x)$.

Comment: My main problem was the leap from set theory, set notation to functions. For beginners they're usually treated separately in texts, or one, then the other exclusively. For example, I presume the notion of a function being continuous in this example is an assumption taken from the fact that $x$ is universally quantified and $y$ being existentially quantified? IOW, what about the set notation tells me I'm dealing with a continuous function $f(x) = x^{1/3}$?

Comment: see my answer...

Comment: @147pm At the point you're proving this statement, it's not appropriate to talk about a function $f(x)=x^{1/3}$ (it begs the question as the statement is trivial once we know such a function exists with domain $\mathbb{R}$, regardless of continuity).  The function whose continuity matters, and whose existence we're not currently trying to prove, is $g(x) = x^3$.

Comment: @BrianMoehring Nice catch.  Makes my answer of only arguable value.

Comment: I guess I'm still after the basic question of what is it about the set notation of the original open sentence makes this a question of continuous-ness? That's what I need to understand first. I see "for all $x$ there exists a $y$ such that $y^{3} = x$ and wonder why we're suddenly talking about continuousness and the IVT.  How did we know to do that? It's like a primitive seeing water and making the leap that it's made of the stuff we breath and the stuff burning in the sun. Huh? all us other primitives say. And _Every real number has a cube root_ doesn't help. Again, how is that IVT?

Comment: IVT has the rough form $$\forall x \in (a,b), \exists y \in \mathbb{R}, f(y)=x$$ Compare that to your problem.

Comment: @Brian Moehring: Aha! Now we're getting somewhere! Can you direct me to a good intro text that explores this set theory-to-analysis connection? I would have never known, guessed this.

Comment: @Brian Moehring: Or maybe I should put this aside and just get through Tom Apostol first...

Answer (score 3):

I will relabel your notation. For all $a\in\mathbb{R}$, there exists $b\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $b^{3}=a$.

Suppose first that $a>0$. Define $f(x)=x^{3}-a$. Then $f$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$. Then $f(a+1)=(a+1)^{3}-a>0$ and $f(-(a+1))=(-a-1)^{3}-a<0$. By the intermediate value theorem, there exists $b\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $f(b)=0$, or equivalently, $b^{3}=a$.

The case for $a<0$ is similar.

The case when $a=0$ is trivial.

Comment: As I said in the above comment, I'm not clear on why, how the set notation becomes the guaranteed continuous function $f(x) = x^{(1/3)}$ how can we assume that by just looking at the set notation? Also, your step from defining $f(x) = x^3 - a$ to "Then $f$ is continuous." has me confused. Why? Can you direct me to more proof examples like yours?

Comment: Just posted an answer to resolve the question of 147pm.

Answer (score 0):

First, see the comment of Brian Moehring, following the original question.  This indicates that the demonstration below, that $f(x) = x^{(1/3)}$ is a continuous function, is not pertinent.

So much analysis there, that I can't bring myself to delete it.  However, I have added an Addendum to address the issue of the continuity of $(x^3).$

---

Responding to a comment/question from the OP:

Given $f:\Bbb{R}\to \Bbb{R}$ such that $f(x) = x^{(1/3)}.$

Demonstration that for all $x_0 \in \Bbb{R}, ~f(x)~$ is continuous at $x = x_0$:

Personally, I found the answers given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/107732/fx-x-frac13-is-continuous-at-any-p-neq-0), [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3349750/is-x1-3-continuous), and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3464074/proving-that-fx-x1-3-is-absolutely-continuous) to be somewhat sophisticated.  It seems reasonable to (instead) provide a (primitive) $\epsilon, \delta$ proof.

**Definition of continuity:**

- $f(x)$ is defined at $(x = x_0)$.
- $\forall \epsilon > 0, ~\exists \delta > 0~$ such that
  $0 < |x - x_0| < \delta \implies |f(x) - f(x_0)| < \epsilon.$

Clearly, the first constraint above is satisfied, for all $x_0 \in \Bbb{R}.$

What the second constraint is saying, in effect, is that for each $(x_0)$, there exists a fixed finite limit $L$, such that $\lim_{x\to x_0} f(x) = L$ and that in all cases, $L = f(x_0)$.

---

**Intermediate Results**

**Lemma 1:**
$a < b \iff a^3 < b^3$.

Proof: 
$g(x) = x^3 \implies g'(x) = 3x^2.$ 
Therefore, $g(x)$ is a strictly increasing function, throughout $\Bbb{R}.$

**Lemma 2:**

1. $~~~\displaystyle 0 < \delta < x_0, ~~~0 < \epsilon < x_0^{(1/3)},  
   ~~~ \delta < \left[3x_0^{(2/3)}\epsilon - 3x_0^{(1/3)}\epsilon^2\right] ~~~\implies $

   $~~~\displaystyle \left[x_0^{(1/3)} - \epsilon\right] < (x_0 - \delta)^{(1/3)}.$
2. $~~~\displaystyle 0 < \delta < x_0, ~~~0 < \epsilon,  
   ~~~ \delta < \left[3x_0^{(2/3)}\epsilon\right] ~~~\implies $ 
   $~~~\displaystyle \left[x_0^{(1/3)} + \epsilon\right] > (x_0 + \delta)^{(1/3)}.$

Proof:
Using Lemma 1, I can show (for example) that $R < S$ by showing that $R^3 < S^3.$

$\displaystyle \left[x_0^{(1/3)} - \epsilon\right]^3
= x_0 - 3x_0^{(2/3)}\epsilon + 3x_0^{(1/3)}\epsilon^2 - \epsilon^3.$ 
By assumption, this is less than $(x_0 - \delta).$

Similarly, 
$\displaystyle \left[x_0^{(1/3)} + \epsilon\right]^3
= x_0 + 3x_0^{(2/3)}\epsilon + 3x_0^{(1/3)}\epsilon^2 + \epsilon^3.$ 
By assumption, this is greater than $(x_0 + \delta).$

---

**Proof of Second Constraint**

From the premise, you have that 
$$- \delta < (x - x_0) < \delta \iff (x_0 - \delta) < x < (x_0 + \delta).\tag{1}$$

From the conclusion you **want to establish** that 
$$ - \epsilon < x^{(1/3)} - x_0^{(1/3)} < \epsilon \iff
\left[x_0^{(1/3)} - \epsilon\right] < x^{(1/3)} < \left[x_0^{(1/3)} + \epsilon\right].\tag2$$

$\underline{\text{Case 1:}~x_0 > 0.}$

Use the following specifications:
$$
\text{If} ~~\left[x_0^{(1/3)} > \epsilon\right]
~~\text{then}~~
\delta = \min\left\{ ~\frac{x_0}{2}, ~\left[x_0^{(2/3)}\epsilon - x_0^{(1/3)}\epsilon^2\right] ~\right\}.$$

$$
\text{Otherwise}~~
\delta = \min\left\{ ~\frac{x_0}{2}, ~\left[x_0^{(2/3)}\epsilon\right] ~\right\}.$$

It is assumed that $\epsilon > 0$ and that $\delta$ is as specified above. 
From this, you know that $x_0 - \delta > 0.$

Using the specification, Lemma 1 and inequality 1 above,   you have that 
$\displaystyle 0 < (x_0 - \delta)^{(1/3)} < x^{(1/3)} < (x_0 + \delta)^{(1/3)}.$

Using the specification and Lemma 2, you know immediately that 
$\displaystyle \left[x_0 + \delta\right]^{(1/3)} < \left[x_0^{(1/3)} + \epsilon\right].$

If $~~x_0^{(1/3)} - \epsilon \leq 0,~~$ then this immediately establishes that 
$\displaystyle x_0^{(1/3)} - \epsilon < \left[x_0 - \delta\right]^{(1/3)}.$

Otherwise, the specification, with Lemma 2, establishes that 
$\displaystyle x_0^{(1/3)} - \epsilon < \left[x_0 - \delta\right]^{(1/3)}.$

Therefore, the specification for $\delta$ establishes inequality (2) above.

---

$\underline{\text{Case 2:}~x_0 < 0.}$

Define $~y_0 = -x_0 \implies $

- $y_0 > 0.$
- $x_0^{(1/3)} = - y_0^{(1/3)}.$

For all $~x < 0,~$ define $~y = -x \implies $

- $y > 0.$
- $x^{(1/3)} = - y^{(1/3)}.$

Assume that $\epsilon > 0$.
Further assume that Case 1 is invoked, so that $\delta$ is specified so that whenever

$$- \delta < (y - y_0) < \delta \iff (y_0 - \delta) < y < (y_0 + \delta)\tag{3}$$

then, the following is satisfied:

$$ - \epsilon < y^{(1/3)} - y_0^{(1/3)} < \epsilon \iff
\left[y_0^{(1/3)} - \epsilon\right] < y^{(1/3)} < \left[y_0^{(1/3)} + \epsilon\right].\tag4$$

Then, inequality 3 above is satisfied if and only if 
$|y - y_0| < \delta \iff |x - x_0| < \delta.$

Further, inequality 4 above is satisfied is and only 
$\left|y^{(1/3)} - y_0^{(1/3)}\right| < \epsilon \iff 
\left|x^{(1/3)} - x_0^{(1/3)}\right| < \epsilon.$

Therefore, continuity is established for all $x_0 < 0.$

---

$\underline{\text{Case 3:}~x_0 = 0.}$

Set $\displaystyle \delta = \frac{1}{2}\epsilon^3 \implies \delta^{(1/3)} < \epsilon,$ by Lemma 1.

Then, using Lemma 1 repeatedly,

$-\delta < x < \delta \implies$

$- \epsilon < -\delta^{(1/3)} < x^{(1/3)} < \delta^{(1/3)} < \epsilon.$

Therefore, continuity is established for $(x_0 = 0).$

---

---

---

**Addendum**
Let $h(x) = x^3.$ 
Prove that $h(x)$ is continuous everywhere.

First of all, I strongly suspect that this has been proven somewhere on MathSE.  However, I could not find such a proof, which indicates that the OP will also have trouble finding such a proof.

Therefore, I will provide a proof below.

Analysis will be very similar to the analysis in the original answer.

Given: 
$$- \delta < (x - x_0) < \delta \iff (x_0 - \delta) < x < (x_0 + \delta).\tag{5}$$

To Prove: 
$$ - \epsilon < x^3 - x_0^3 < \epsilon \iff
\left[x_0^3 - \epsilon\right] < x^3 < \left[x_0^3 + \epsilon\right].\tag6$$

This proof is much easier than the previous proof.

$\underline{\text{Case 1:} ~x_0 > 0.}$

Use the following specification:
$$
\delta = \min\left\{ ~\frac{x_0}{2}, \frac{1}{2}, ~\left[\frac{\epsilon}
{2 \times (3x_0^2 + 3x_0 + 1)}\right]~\right\}.$$

It is assumed that $\epsilon > 0$ and that $\delta$ is as specified above. 
From this, you know that $x_0 - \delta > 0.$

Using the specification, Lemma 1 and inequality 5 above,   you have that 
$\displaystyle 0 < (x_0 - \delta)^3 < x^3 < (x_0 + \delta)^3.$

Further, since $\delta < 1$, 
$(x_0 + \delta)^3 = x_0^3 + 3x_0^2\delta + 3x_0\delta^2 + \delta^3$ 
$< x_0^3 + \delta(3x_0^2 + 3x_0 + 1) < x_0^3 + \epsilon.$

Also, you have that 
$\epsilon > \delta(3x_0^2 + 3x_0 + 1)$ 
$> 3x_0^2 \delta + 3x_0\delta^2 + \delta^3$ 
$> 3x_0^2 \delta - 3x_0\delta^2 + \delta^3$.

This implies that 
$x_0^3 - \epsilon < x_0^3 - 3x_0^2 \delta + 3x_0\delta^2 - \delta^3 = (x_0 - \delta)^3.$

Therefore, when $x_0 > 0$, inequality (6) above is established, so $h(x) = x^3$ is continuous at $x_0$.

---

$\underline{\text{Case 2:} ~x_0 < 0.}$
Adopting the nomenclature of Case 2 in the original answer, the analysis is virtually identical to that of Case 2.

That is,
$x_0^3 = -y_0^3.$ 
$x^3 = -y^3.$
$|x - x_0| = |y - y_0|$. 
$|x^3 - x_0^3| = |y^3 - y_0^3|.$

Therefore, $h(x) = x^3$ is also continuous at $x_0 < 0.$

---

$\underline{\text{Case 3:} ~x_0 = 0.}$

Use the following specification:
$$
\delta = \min\left\{ \frac{1}{2}, ~\left[\frac{\epsilon}
{2}\right]~\right\}.$$

It is assumed that $\epsilon > 0$ and that $\delta$ is as specified above.

Using the specification, Lemma 1 and inequality 5 above,   you have that 
$\displaystyle - \delta^3 < x^3 < \delta^3.$

Further, since $\delta < 1, ~~\delta^3 < \delta < \epsilon.$

Therefore, 
$-\epsilon < -\delta < -\delta^3 < x^3 < \delta^3 < \delta < \epsilon.$

Therefore, when $x_0 = 0$, inequality (6) above is established, so $h(x) = x^3$ is continuous at $x_0 = 0.$